# Where is generate makefile menu option?

Tags: xamarin.mac, makefile

I have Xamarin 5.9.6 (build 23) running on a MacBook Pro.

Currently, I'm working on a large C# project and I need to compile it and run it on a server.

But first, I need to generate a makefile so that, in the server, I just issue the "make" command and then run the project after the compilation succeeds. 
The problem is that I can't seem to find the menu item to generate a makefile.

Anyone can please let me know how I can generate a self contained makefile (autotools compatible)?

By the way, the server does have mono installed but not Xamarin or any other IDE.

Comment: Wild guess, but without having Xamarin installed on your server, you're going to have to do the compilation on your MacBook Pro and move the compiled program/application to the server afterwards, where the Mono installation may be sufficient to allow you to run.  More than that, I have no clue; I don't recognize C# as a language (looks more like a musical note to me), and I'd not heard of Xamarin as a product before.

Comment: Are you sure generating a standalone Makefile is something Xamarin can do? That seems like a potentially odd thing for it to want to do to me.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done in an earlier IDE version called monodevelop (and I have done it myself in my ex-windows laptop). In that version, there used to be a menu option "Export makefile" under the project menu. Unfortunately, I can neither find this old version IDE nor this option in new version Xamarin. To see how the option looks under the menu, look at this URL: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-xamarin-studio/9781783550814/ch02s09.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that the option is disabled by default in my version of Xamarin. To enable it:

1. in the main menu, open "Xamarin Studio -> Add-in Manager"
2. expand "project import and export" item
3. under this item, there is a "Makefile generation" option, click it
4. click enable button.

Now the option can be found under the "Project" menu.